# Error while running JavaFx application on Mac

Tags: java, macos, maven, javafx

- I devlop one javaFx application and create nave bundle of that application
  with the help of com.zenjava maven plugin for the Mac.
- The native bundle that is .dmg is created but while running application it throws following error

  "vm_info: java Hotspot(TM) 64-Bit server VM (24.0-b56) for bsd-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_40-b43) , build on Aug 26 2013 by "java_re" with gcc 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658)(LLVM build 2336.11.00"
- bundle is created with jdk:1.7.0_40.jdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the jre you are using.

"vm_info: java Hotspot(TM) 64-Bit server VM (24.0-b56) for bsd-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_40-b43) , build on Aug 26 2013 by "java_re" with gcc 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658)(LLVM build 2336.11.00"

bundle is created with jdk:1.7.0_40.jdk

the above bundle you are creating containing jre having some problem so just check JRE,
and try it again.
It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, why to use such maven plugins, if there's javafxpackager cli tool included with JDK nowadays and if you want to insert this, also there's ant tasks. See http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafxpackager001.htm and http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_task_reference001.htm

Comment: The Maven pluging is easy to use as compare to javafxpackager.And the native bundle created by this pluging is same as the native bundle created by javafxpackager.

Comment: I just wanna say it's ok for me and not falling when using packager or ant tasks.